# Conversion problems with Union and Option Strict on

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, union

i have a Problem with UNION for LINQ to SQL

I have my LINQ query

```
Dim dc As New ContainerDB.DataClassesDataContext()
    Dim test = (From container In dc.GetTable(Of tbl_container)() Where container.pkContainerID = iPkContainerID).Union( _
                    From containerHist In dc.GetTable(Of tbl_containerHIST)() Where containerHist.pkContainerID = iPkContainerID)
```

I always get implicit conversion error

> System.Linq.IQueryable(Of
>   ContainerDB.tbl_containerHIST) in
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of
>   ContainerDB.tbl_container).

Whats wrong on that query? 
What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `Option Infer On`. This will enable the use of type inference, which you seem to be doing here:

```
Dim test =
```

**EDIT**

Also, you need to use [anonymous types:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx#Y570), so tbl_container and tbl_containerHIST can be compared:

```
Dim test = (From container In dc.GetTable(Of tbl_container)() 
            Where container.pkContainerID = iPkContainerID 
            Select New With{ ... }).Union( _
            From containerHist In dc.GetTable(Of tbl_containerHIST)() 
            Where containerHist.pkContainerID = iPkContainerID 
            Select New With{ ... })
```

Comment: Hi Rewinder, thx for your input. but it doesnt work. _"System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[ContainerDB.tbl_containerHIST]" cannot be convertered to Typ "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ContainerDB.tbl_container]"._

Comment: @SwissGuy: Ah, the problem seems to be that tbl_containerHIST and tbl_container are two different types. The return of a union should be of IEnumerable(Of ContainerDB.tbl_container). Is it possible to convert tbl_containerHIST to tbl_container?

Comment: Hey rewinder, the cointainerHIST has only 1 more column for  deleted, updated. is there a way to access this?  same error for: `Dim test = (From container In dc.GetTable(Of tbl_container)()
                        Where container.pkContainerID = iPkContainerID
                        Select New With {.ContainerID = container.pkContainerID}).Union( _
                        From containerHist In dc.GetTable(Of tbl_containerHIST)()
                        Where containerHist.pkContainerID = iPkContainerID
                        Select New With {.ContainerID = containerHist.pkContainerID})`

Comment: @SwissGuy: Well, it can be accessed, but for a union to succeed all types need to have same properties/columns.